# Find ordering of directed weighted graph maximizing sum of edges 'going up'

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider the following problem. Given a weighted directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n = |V|$, find an ordering $\pi: \{1,...n\} \to V$ of the vertices that maximizes
$$
\sum_{i<j} w_{\pi(i),\pi(j)}.
$$
Has this problem been studied in the literature? Does a simple greedy approach work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Never mind, I found it - it's the linear ordering problem.